# Question related to phrase search in lucene/solr?

Tags: lucene, solr

I have question is it possible to perform a phrase search with wild cards in solr/lucene as if i have two queries both have exactly same results.
One is:

```
+Contents:"change market"
```

and the other is:

```
+Contents:"change* market"
```

I assumed the second should match "changes market", but it does not return any matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in Lucene with [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/contrib-misc/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html). Solr has facility to plug in custom query parser with [QParserPlugin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#QParserPlugin). You can possibly use these two to have desired functionality with Solr as well.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is not possible to search for wild cards with in phrase.
You might want to consider using two queries with proximity search.(q=change* market&qs=1)
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_search_for_one_term_near_another_term_.28say.2C_.22batman.22_and_.22movie.22.29

Comment: I had tried wht you r saying but unfortunately it doesn't work as i guess it will get documents having change* or market in the contents.

Comment: @Ahsan: it depends on default operator in schema, you can set it to 'AND' to get the desired result.